# Jenkins Maven SoapUI Java403 Forbidden error

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, soapui

I have an automation which is written in SoapUI. I am kicking it off using Java/Maven/SoapUI API. Basically I can kick off soapUI automation from Java > Project > Run As> Maven Test. It works perfectly.

Now I committed my project to SVN and Integrating to local Jenkins. When I click Build now, I get following error.

```
23:11:49,514 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Attempt 1 to execute request
23:11:49,514 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Sending request: POST /myApp/ProcessorService HTTP/1.1
23:11:50,377 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
23:11:50,388 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Connection can be kept alive for 15000 MILLISECONDS
```

One thing i wanted to to mention is that my SoapUI project has some security (.JKS) files. I am not sure it is causing the problem or not.

Also whenever I run a job through jenkins, it tries to create soapui-settings.xml in C: drive. As this is my organization laptop, I do not have access to create a file in C Drive. Not sure this could be a problem or not.

Please help.

Thanks,

Comment: A response code of `403` would be consistent with an SSL certificate problem, so I think you are already on the right track.

Comment: So i played with my eclipse automation code. I removed soapui-settings.xml file and replicated error in eclipse(403) -- same as jenkins. this means jenkins tries to create soapui-settings.xml file under c drive but i do not have permission to create a file there.  Any idea how can i change default path of soapui-settings.xml in jenkins/maven CI.

Comment: What happens if `soapsettings.xml` be already there?  Maybe you can create it.

Comment: I can't create in C Drive. I do not have permission. At this point I was wondering, how to change this default path.